# What are the different ways to call a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Please tell me the different ways to call a constructor. Say class A is main class, and i need to call the constructor of class B from inside class A. Are there different ways we can do this?? In Java.

Comment: java. I forgot to add that.

Comment: With `new` or via reflection or JNI, for a start.

Comment: Read the book my friend.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of calling a Java constructor is like this:

```
ClassA theClass = new ClassA();
```

If your constructor accepts parameters (say, three ints), then you can modify your code to this:

```
ClassA theClass = new ClassA(10, 20, 30);
```

**Update (2) March 8, 2015:** When you add parameters to a constructor like above you can access them like this (this is ClassA):

```
int firstInt;
int secondInt;
int thirdInt;

public ClassA(int fInt, int sInt, int tInt) {
    firstInt = fInt;
    secondInt = sInt;
    thirdInt = tInt;
}

public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println(firstInt + " " + secondInt + " " + thirdInt);
}
```

You can then call various methods like this:

```
theClass.methodName(params);
```

---

### Update (1) March 8, 2015

As dragon66 pointed out in the comments, you can also use reflection, although some tests have shown it to be slower than normal instantiation. It works like this:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("complete.classpath");
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
```

You can then call a method with:

```
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", noparams);
method.invoke(obj, null);
```

Comment: Reflection is another way to call default constructor.

Comment: @dragon66 It is another way to call any constructor.

Comment: Thank you. 
If inside the constructor, I had to return an integer value back to the main class, where this constructor was initially called from. Then, to what variable can I assign that value to? and how?

Comment: @sanal Not sure if you noticed, but I updated the answer again to solve your question.